# Bernoulli Polynomials and Euler summation

Tags: integration, summation, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I'm given the Euler summation formula in it's simplest terms,  namely
$$
\sum_{v = 0}^{n} f(v)=\frac{1}{2}\left( f(n)+f(0) \right) 
 +  \int_{0}^{n} f(x)\textrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{n} \left( 
  x  -  \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}
  \right) f'(x)\textrm{d}x 
.$$
Given the information that $f$ has $k$ continuous derivatives, I should extend this formula by repeated integration by parts. Denoting $\left(x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ with $P_1(x)$ I obtain
$$
 \int_{0}^{n} P_1(x) f'(x)\textrm{d}x 
 = \left[ P_2(x)f'(x) \right]_0^n- \int_{0}^{n} P_2f''(x)\textrm{d}x
$$
but now the question arises how one should define $P_2(x)$ (i.e.
the antiderivative of $P_1(x)$)
$$
 P_1(x) = \begin{cases}
  x-\frac{1}{2}, \quad  0\le x < 1\\
  x-n-\frac{1}{2}, \quad n \le x < n+1 \ (n \ge 1)
 \end{cases}
$$
so I thought one could choose
$$
P_2(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x, \quad 0\le x < 1 \\[5pt]
  \frac{1}{2}x^2-nx-\frac{1}{2}x, \quad n \le x < n+1 \ (n \ge 1)
 \end{cases}
$$
Is my  choice for $P_2$ reasonable?

When trying to  verify the correctness of my choice I considered

\begin{align*}
 \sum_{i = 0}^{n} i 
 =  \int_{0}^{n} x\textrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\left( 
  n + 0
  \right) 
  + \left[ P_2 \right]_0^n - \int_{0}^{n} 0\cdot P_3\textrm{d}x 
  =  \frac{1}{2}n^2  +  \frac{1}{2}n 
  +  \left[ \frac{1}{2}n^2  - n^2 - \frac{1}{2}n \right]
  = 0
.\end{align*}
So apparently I made some mistake ...

Comment: The usual choice is $P_2(x)= \frac{1}{2!} B_2(x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor)$ where $B_2(t)=t^2-t+\frac{1}{6}$ is the second Bernoulli polynomial. So your coice is almost right except the constant term is missing.

Comment: @Gary but there isn't only one correct answer, right? Only some make computation easier, or am I mistaken?

Comment: If you choose the constant to be zero, the thing you integrate out will be $0$, so you do not gain a new term.

Comment: @Gary but for $P_2$ as the OP defined it $\left[P_2(x)f'(x)\right]_0^n$ would yield $1/2n^2 - n^2 - 1/2n = -1/2n^2 - 1/2n$? (times $f'(x)$)

Comment: @Renny I did not read it carefully enough, sorry. The OP's notation is misleading anyway as the upper limit of integration $n$ and the $n$ in the definition of the polynomials are not the same.

Comment: @Gary yes, this might be misleading. But then the OP's choice is also correct, right?

Comment: Mathematically seems correct, but likely useless since we want the dependence to appear only in the argument of the derivatives of $f$ and not in the coefficients.

Comment: @Gary could you maybe explain this a bit in more detail?

Comment: @Gary would my polynomials work in a  computation?

Comment: @Gary could I e.g. determine a closed form for $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^2$ with those polynomials?

Comment: @Sebastian You can get the formula for that sum but it is a rather complicated way with the $P_2$ you chose. Bernoulli polynomials are used in the Euler$-$Maclaurin formula for a good reason.

Comment: @Gary I totally  understand that my choice is probably really inefficient concerning computations. Could you still demonstrate how one would achieve a formula for the sum of $i^2$ with the polynomials I defined because I tried it but somehow didn't arrive at the correct one.